# Neo4j2.3 tinkerpop

Tags: neo4j, tinkerpop-blueprint

Right now we are using Neo4j 1.9.9 version(embedded mode) with tinkerpop blueprints 2.4 API. We are planning to upgrade our Neo4j to 2.3. But I see that blueprints is not compatible with neo 2.3. Since our system is stable now we are trying to upgrade our neo4j without disturbing the crud layer much. 
1.Can any one help me here to understand why blueprints is not compatible with 2.3? 
2. If I plan to use spring-data from my understanding it is not for embedded mode.Can some one share if you faced this scenario and how you approached the problem?